# Check input and convert it to appropriate type to prevent XSS

Tags: javascript, html, security, frontend, xss

Lets say I get "name" from a user and he enters `<script>alert("you got xss!");</script>`

But on the server I convert:
`name= name_from_frontend.toString();` before saving it to db. 
Similarly, I check for `int using parseInt()`

`float using parseFloat()`
`boolean using typeof(variable_name)` and so on.

Is there still a need of escaping `<`, `&` and other characters as mentioned by [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) to prevent XSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enapupe is broadly correct, but the part of his answer which says `You probably need to strip evil tags such as script, etc.` - is not very clear. 
 
The correct statement would be - **You absolutely have to remove XSS using [OWASP guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)), converting to string or not converting to string will not make a difference**!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `toString()` on a string type doesn't help. You probably need to strip evil tags such as `script`,  etc.

Most server-side languages such as python (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach), php (`strip_tags()`), etc have function libraries focused on cleanup evil markup so you can safely use that input later.

If you want a JS solution you should check https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html, which does the job but is intended for use with Node. Example:

```
clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty, {
  allowedTags: [ 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a' ],
  allowedAttributes: {
    'a': [ 'href' ]
  }
});
```

Comment: how will `"<script> alert('evil XSS!'); </script>"` be able to generate xss in html (its a string)?

Comment: Everything depends on what you are going to do with that data.. In the beginnings was a common practice to `print` user-inserted html by using server-side language..

Comment: I will use user data in client side templates which may do eval() or interpolation. I use mustache -> {{ and {{=